# How can I get a YouTube video upload date?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, youtube

I've been trying to get the upload date of a YouTube video (as the following picture shows) with Selenium in Python.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```py
! pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
! pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoR72I5BGUU")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

upload_date=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="info-strings"]/yt-formatted-string')

print(upload_date)
```

However, no matter I used `upload_date=soup.findAll('span', class_='style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')` or `upload_date=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="info-strings"]/yt-formatted-string')`, it didn't work.

If anyone knows where the problem is, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below **CSS_SELECTOR**:

```
span#dot+yt-formatted-string[class$='ytd-video-primary-info-renderer']
```

**Code:**

```
upload_date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span#dot+yt-formatted-string[class$='ytd-video-primary-info-renderer']")
print(upload_date.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the "date", you can use a CSS selector `#info-strings yt-formatted-string` which will select the HTML *ID* `info-strings` and then the `info-strings` tag.

Also, you should wait for the page to correctly load before trying to scrape the "date" by using `WebDriverWait` (additional imports are required, see the code example).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoR72I5BGUU")

# Waits 20 seconds for the "date" the appear on the webpage
date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#info-strings yt-formatted-string")
    )
)

print(date.text)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Jan 25, 2018
```

See also:

- [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)